# Why data is not inserted in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I try to insert array to table:

**Inserting data is:**

```
$item = [
  "lastname" => "Husey"
  "firstname" => "Fik"
  "middlename" => "Akif"
  "birthday" => "1981-04-09"
  "company" => "XXX"
  "document_number" => 16428285.0
  "pincode" => "QT0FE12"
  "code" => 19283746564923.0
  "idEvent" => "17"
]
```

**Insert into model:**

```
Visitor::create($item);
```

**Model Visitor is:**

```
class Visitor extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public $table = 'visitors';

    public $fillable = [
    'firstname', 
    'lastname', 
    'middlename', 
    'document_number', 
    'pincode', 
    'ckecked', 
    'date_cheked',
    'user_checked',
    'company',
    'code',
    'idEvent',
    'date',
    'birthday'
    ];
}
```

**Dump SQL is:**

```
CREATE TABLE `visitors` (
  `idVisitor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `middlename` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `document_number` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `pincode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `ckecked` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_cheked` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_checked` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idEvent` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `birthday` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I dont get any exception or errors.

If to make the following:

```
$s = Visitor::create($item);
dd($s);
```

It returns full model data, but DB table is empty!

Comment: make sure you have database connection proper working in `.env` file

Comment: Sure, it is I have connection

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What's the error reporting level? Is there anything written to the server's error log, or to your application's?

Comment: No error logs, no messages, no exceptions

Answer (score 0):

i think you miss , in your array

```
$item = [
 "lastname" => "Husey",
 "firstname" => "Fik",
 "middlename" => "Akif",
 "birthday" => "1981-04-09",
 "company" => "XXX",
 "document_number" => 16428285.0,
 "pincode" => "QT0FE12",
 "code" => 19283746564923.0,
 "idEvent" => "17"
]
```

Comment: I'm sure he doesn't, as this would throw a clear error message

Comment: What is missed?, why I dont get error or any message

Answer (score 0):

You are missing comma in your array and code is working fine, update your code with this.

```
 $item = [
        "lastname" => "Husey",
        "firstname" => "Fik",
        "middlename" => "Akif",
        "birthday" => "1981-04-09",
        "company" => "XXX",
        "document_number" => 16428285.0,
        "pincode" => "QT0FE12",
        "code" => 19283746564923.0,
        "idEvent" => "17"
    ];

    $visitor = Visitor::create($item);

    return $visitor;
```